# NDB JsonProperty quota impact compared to old datastore properties?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I seem to remember the old datastore properties have something like 2 **datastore write operations** (DWOs) per storage, and perhaps a few more depending on how they are indexed.

In the old datastore, I would frequently store everything I didn't need to index in a JSON string and store that as a TextProperty to save on multiples of writes.

Having gotten used to saving and working with everything in JSON straight from the datastore, when switching to the NDB for a new app, I naturally used the NDB JsonProperty.

As is usual, I became paranoid about optimization the first time I checked out my quota limits (quintessential free-quota-limit user experience ?), and noticed all the datastore writes (which consisted entirely of models with only JsonProperties) were clocking up a lot of DWO quota.

Immediately I wondered : Does GAE DataStore make multiples of writes depending on the structure of the JsonProperty? Or does it just store the whole property blob to the datastore in as few DWOs as are required for a "blob" store?

I thought the latter, and remembered reading so in the docs, but the massive quota consumption (quintessential free-quota-limit user paranoia ?), made me wonder if maybe using JsonProperty was not as efficient as using the old datastore and saving the JSON strings as TextProperty -- which are certainly unstructured blobs.

It would be good if this could be cleared up definitively, so I can get back to the "appengine promise" of focussing *only on the app.* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datastore is runtime agnostic and has no idea there is such a thing as `python`, `ndb` or JSON, so it can't index/write differently based on your data. In the [implementation](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py?r=30c578bfe60c63d858aefaeb8e48a63e64ee872e#1680), `JsonProperty` is a `BlobProperty` and just uses `json` to serialize and de-serialize data:

```
class JsonProperty(BlobProperty):
  def __init__(self, name=None, compressed=False, json_type=None, **kwds):
```

A `BlobProperty` [can be](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py?r=30c578bfe60c63d858aefaeb8e48a63e64ee872e#1500) `indexed` or not and also `compressed` or not:

```
class BlobProperty(Property):
  _indexed = False
  _compressed = False
  def __init__(self, name=None, compressed=False, **kwds):
```

It seems you may be comparing a situation where `compressed` was `True` to the default of `False`. Try setting it to `True` and maybe posting some raw numbers to compare (even some numbers from the `db` case to get a sense).

## UPDATE:

I wasn't sure I was clear enough on this, and after Guido's comment it's clear I wasn't. **The datastore writes for your `ndb` blob property will be exactly the same as the datastore writes for your `db` blob property.** These numbers change based on whether the entities exist or not, and whether the properties are indexed or not. My comment about `compressed` was to address any other performance/bandwidth/size issues you may have been confused by.

If you check out the [billing page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing), there is a mapping from high-level operations to low-level operations. Relevant to what you are asking about we have:

- **New Entity Put (per entity, regardless of entity size)**: 2 writes + 2 writes per indexed property value + 1 write per composite index value
- **Existing Entity Put (per entity)**: 1 write + 4 writes per modified indexed property value + 2 writes per modified composite index value

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer (and links!). I will investigate further.

Comment: Compression has nothing to do with it -- DWOs are counted regardless of the size.  Indexing does indeed matter.  But I'd look in other parts of your app.  Have you tried Appstats yet?

Comment: Also, do checkout the dev_appserver datastore viewer (localhost:8080/_ah/admin). When viewing datastore entities you'll see an extra column indicating the number of datastore 'Write Ops'. You will see this number change as you change the number of properties with `indexed=True` (note: `True` is the default). Also note that after changing your Model class so that properties are explicitly marked `indexed=False`, you'll still incur extra DWOs the first time you update each entity as the datastore deletes the index rows for previously indexed properties.